# Function returning function and not float in f#

Tags: f#, functional-programming

Sorry for the really bad title, but I couldn't come up with a better one...

I am following Structure and interpretation of computer programs and am trying to do the example from section 1.1.7 about Netwon's method of seccessive approximation for finding square roots.

I try to implement it in F# and i believe I'm pretty close to getting there, but probably There is some kind of syntactic problem.

Here is my code (I used linqpad, hence the Dump()), below follows the question

```
let square a = a * a

let average a b = (a + b)/2.0

let a = average 2.0 1.0
a.Dump()

let improve guess x = average guess x

let i = improve 2.0 1.0
i.Dump()

let goodEnough guess x = abs (x - square(guess)) < 0.001

let g = goodEnough 3.0 4.0
g.Dump()

let g2 = goodEnough 2.0 4.0
g2.Dump()

let rec sqrtIterator guess x =
  if goodEnough guess x then guess
  else sqrtIterator(improve(guess x) x)

let sqrt x = sqrtIterator 1.0 x
```

I get an error on the recursive call to sqrtIterator saying:
This expression was expected to have type     `float`     but here has type     `float -> float`.

So it seems I am missing a parameter making it return a function taking one parameter, but I can not see whats wrong?

Comment: By the way my improve was wrong, this is correct: let improve guess x = average guess (x / guess)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Changing `sqrtIterator(improve(guess x) x)` to `sqrtIterator (improve guess x) x` would solve the problem.

From the first part of the expression in `sqrtIterator`:

`if goodEnough guess x then guess`

the type checker knows that `guess` is a `float` since `goodEnough` has already had type `float -> float`.

The `else` branch is expected to has type `float` as well. Consequently, `sqrtIterator` has type `float -> float -> float`.

However, you provided `sqrtIterator(improve(guess x) x)` in the `else` branch.  The outermost parentheses indicate that `improve(guess x) x` is a single parameter which supposes to be a `float`.

Now `sqrtIterator(improve(guess x) x)` returns `float -> float` hence the above error message.

Answer (score 4):

Here is the problem fixed:

```
let rec sqrtIterator guess x =
  if goodEnough guess x then guess
  else sqrtIterator (improve guess x) x
```

Your parens were wrong.

Answer (score 4):

Your bracketing in `sqrtIterator` is slightly off - you need

```
  else sqrtIterator (improve guess x) x
```